# Прочесть файл только с помощью ls

Tags: linux, bash

В терминале linux требуется прочитать файл -data.txt- только при помощи команды ls.  Есть идеи?

Comment: Задание конечно бредовое. Зачем если есть для этого `cat`?

Comment: Определите термин **прочитать**. Забегая вперёд, если про содержимое файла идёт речь, то это невозможно сделать с помощью команды *ls*.

Comment: Надо как-то обмануть *ls* так, что бы она подумала, что этот файл - директория. Тогда она попытается распечатать список файлов из этой "директории" и, по крайней мере, в сообщениях об ошибках будут фигурировать куски текста из этого файла.

Comment: можно всегда сделать правильный алиас. и тогда даже rm будет читать файлы.

Answer (score 2):

> при помощи **команды** ls

вот в этом месте и кроется уловка.

ведь **программа** `/bin/ls` такого, естественно, не умеет.

а вот **команда, выполняемая оболочкой**, может запустить произвольную программу. например, `/bin/cat`. ну а определить действия команды можно по-разному. например, с помощью встроенной команды оболочки `alias` (для создания псевдонимов команд):

```
$ alias ls=/bin/cat
```

проверяем:

```
$ ls файл
здесь будет результат выполнения программы /bin/cat
с аргументом "файл", т.е. содержимое этого файла
```

или с помощью определения функции. для начала удаляем псевдоним:

```
$ unalias ls
```

и создаём функцию. либо так:

```
$ function ls { /bin/cat $@; }
```

либо так (просто другой синтаксис):

```
$ ls () { /bin/cat $@; }
```

проверка даст аналогичный результат.

Comment: Ну это какое-то извращённое сознание должно быть у преподавателя, чтобы такие тонкости в задачи вводить. Так, надо название по крючкотворчеству вводить, а не по программированию или системному администрированию.